# Prolog write list in pairs

Tags: prolog

I have a list:

```
[a,b,c]
```

I want to print the list like this:

```
a -> b
b -> c
```

So far, I have this code:

```
print([]).
print([H|T]) :- write(H), write(' -> '), nl, print(T).
```

which will produce the following result:

```
a -> 
b -> 
c ->
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your predicate needs to pull more items out of the list. Try:

```
print([]).
print([_]).  % if we're trying to print pairs, we can't print a single item
print([X,Y|T]) :- write(X), write(' -> '), write(Y), nl, print([Y|T]).
```

Answer (score 0):

You could consider to separate the logic - albeit minimal - from IO:

```
pairs([A,B|T], P) :- P = (A,B) ; pairs([B|T], P).
printp(L) :- forall(pairs(L, (A,B)), writeln(A->B)).
```

This way pairs/2 is ready to enumerate your sequence, in case you need to do...